# Basic C++ sockets client

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm attempting to recreate a GUI for work from the ground up, and it'll be my first networked application. To that end, I've been reading all the C/C++ sockets tutorial information I can find, but I've coded myself into a useless couple-hundred lines with that information.

There are two problems (that I know of) with the following code:

1) Once it's connected to the port I'm supposed to be listening to, it should immediately receive the string `99999999%connect`. At that point, I should be able to send a `0` and start receiving the beginning of the day's data. However, I'm not receiving that first message.

2) I'm not sure how to write this in such a way that it won't cause the GTK UI to lock up. That's some basic stuff, I know, but this whole thing is just an off-the-cuff first attempt at sockets.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define UNUSED(x) (void) x

typedef struct
{
  GtkWidget *window, *grid,
            *labelHost, *labelPort, *textFieldHost, *textFieldPort,
            *buttonConnect;
}uiWidgets;

int sockfd = 0;

gboolean on_close_cleanup();
void buttonConnect_on_clicked(GtkButton *button, uiWidgets* widgets);
void connect_to_logview(struct addrinfo *hostname_result);
void listen_for_logview();

int main()
{
  uiWidgets widgets;

  gtk_init(NULL, NULL);

  widgets.window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(widgets.window), "SG GUI V3.00");
  g_signal_connect(widgets.window, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, nullptr);
  g_signal_connect(widgets.window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(on_close_cleanup),
                   nullptr);

  widgets.labelHost = gtk_label_new("Host");
  widgets.labelPort = gtk_label_new("Port");

  widgets.textFieldHost = gtk_entry_new();
  widgets.textFieldPort = gtk_entry_new();

  widgets.buttonConnect = gtk_button_new_with_label("Connect");
  g_signal_connect(widgets.buttonConnect, "clicked",
                   G_CALLBACK(buttonConnect_on_clicked),
                   &widgets);

  widgets.grid = gtk_grid_new();
  gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(widgets.grid), 5);
  gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(widgets.grid), true);
  gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(widgets.grid), true);

  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(widgets.grid), widgets.labelHost, 0, 0, 1, 1);
  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(widgets.grid), widgets.labelPort, 2, 0, 1, 1);
  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(widgets.grid), widgets.textFieldHost, 0, 1, 2, 1);
  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(widgets.grid), widgets.textFieldPort, 2, 1, 1, 1);
  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(widgets.grid), widgets.buttonConnect,  1, 2, 1, 1);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(widgets.window), widgets.grid);
  gtk_widget_show_all(widgets.window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}

gboolean on_close_cleanup()
{
  close(sockfd);
  return false;
}

void buttonConnect_on_clicked(GtkButton *button, uiWidgets* widgets)
{
  UNUSED(button);
  struct addrinfo hints, *hostname_result;
  struct sockaddr_in *hostname_address;
  const gchar *hostname = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widgets->textFieldHost));
  int return_value;
  gchar addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

  if((return_value = getaddrinfo(hostname,
                          gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widgets->textFieldPort)),
                          &hints, &hostname_result)) != 0)
  {
    g_print("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(return_value));
    return;
  }

  for(struct addrinfo *info_itr = hostname_result; info_itr != nullptr;
      info_itr = info_itr->ai_next)
  {
    hostname_address = (struct sockaddr_in *)info_itr->ai_addr;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(hostname_address->sin_addr), addr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    g_print("%s:%s\n", addr, gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widgets->textFieldPort)));
  }

  connect_to_logview(hostname_result);

  freeaddrinfo(hostname_result);
}

void connect_to_logview(struct addrinfo *hostname_result)
{
  int rv = 0;
  sockfd = socket(hostname_result->ai_family, hostname_result->ai_socktype,
                      hostname_result->ai_protocol);

  if(sockfd == -1)
  {
    perror("socket");
  }
  else
  {
    rv = connect(sockfd, hostname_result->ai_addr, hostname_result->ai_addrlen);

    if(rv == -1)
    {
      perror("connect");
    }
    else
    {
      g_print("%s: Looks like we got something!\n", __FUNCTION__);
      listen_for_logview();
    }
  }
}

void listen_for_logview()
{
  fd_set fdset;
  gchar buf[256];
  int nbytes = 0;
  bool exit = false;
  struct timeval tv;

  tv.tv_sec = 2;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  FD_ZERO(&fdset);

  while(!exit)
  {
    if(select(sockfd+1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &tv) == -1)
    {
      perror("select");
      exit = true;
      break;
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &fdset))
    {
      if((nbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0)) <= 0)
      {
        perror("recv");
        close(sockfd);
        FD_CLR(sockfd, &fdset);
        exit = true;
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        g_print("!!!\n%s\n\n", buf);
        close(sockfd);
        FD_CLR(sockfd, &fdset);
        exit = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      g_print("Timed out!\n");
      tv.tv_sec = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

So, what's wrong here? I'm guessing the answers are me simply misusing the tools I've got. I'd be grateful to hear about any other structural/technique issues you see here in addition to the two misbehaviors above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would take your socket code out of your UI code and wrap it up in a neat little class of its own that you can test separately.

Comment: That'll certainly be the direction I go once I get it to start listening properly. For now, it's all in one file just for the sake of simplicity. Once I know what I have to do to listen, I'll start over with actual objects/etc.

Comment: GTK is a venerable C library, not C++. Qt is a C++ one.

Comment: That is evidence of my C roots as well of my bias toward Gnome. ;)

Comment: @musasabi That's putting the cart before the horse. You're doing it in the wrong order. Get it listening properly *by* removing all the UI code, and then put it together if you really must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're zeroing the FD set and never putting anything into it, so you're selecting on an empty FD set, so nothing ever gets selected as readable, writable, whatever, so you're never actually reading. You need to add `sockfd` to the FD set, with the appropriate `FD_*` macro.

You also need to reset the timeout structure every time around the loop.

But as you're using blocking mode there's no need to use `select()` at all. Just do the `recv()`. It will block.

NB if `recv()` returns zero it is end of stream: the peer has disconnected. It is not an error, and calling `perror()` in this case will only print a random error message. Don't do this.

Comment: Thank you. That was clear and obviously something missing. I'll try it as soon as I get a chance. A question, though: would using non-blocking sockets address the GUI lockup, perhaps?

Comment: I just tested it and it did work. I'd still like to hear back on the blocking/non-blocking query, though. =)

Comment: @musasabi The GUI lockup is causing by doing blocking operations in the GUI thread. `select()` is a blocking operation. The solution is to do the network operations in a separate thread.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to use blocking sockets. `connect` blocks the thread till it connected or failed.

You need to use non-blocking sockets so that the connection is established asynchronously.

Comment: Would that be via fcntl(), F_SETFL, and O_NONBLOCK?

Comment: @musasabi You need to use non-blocking sockets *if you want the connection to be established asynchronously.* There's nothing about that in your question, so there's no need to follow this suggestion. In fact 'asynchronously' is the wrong term to use here. All that non-blocking mode connect gets you is the ability to shorten the timeout.

Comment: @EJP _how to write this in such a way that it won't cause the GTK UI to lock up_ - you get that when using blocking sockets in UI thread.

Comment: @EJP _All that non-blocking mode connect gets you is the ability to shorten the timeout._ - that is incorrect.